# Menubar like Wordpress admin menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to find a javascript library (better if can be done usiny jquery) to replicate more or less the functionality of the top menubar of wordpress once you are logged. You can add images/links on the left, on the right, or both sides.

The most javascript menus libraries that I've found are not as nice as this one, some of them only add buttons/link on one side or centered ...

See the attached image.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns) provides this functionality out of the box. Even if you don't need the entire Bootstrap framework, it's easy to separate what you need from the rest.

For a quick and simple sticky navigation bar (with none of the more involved extras, such as drop-down menus, etc.), you can use the following CSS:

```
#bar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:36px;
    background: black;
}
```

... and then add whatever you need to it, e.g.

```
<div id=bar>
    <img class=bar-left src=logo.png />
    <div class=bar-right>Login button!</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.bar-left {
    float:left;
}

.bar-right {
    float:right;
}
```

This works well enough. As for jQuery, you could use it to dynamically add elements to the navbar with its `.append()` and `.prepend()` methods.

Comment: well, for an easy and quick implementation your code works, but then we have to have the submenus that activate/show/hide more options

Comment: You might be able to find such functionality in Bootstrap, namely: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: the more correct answer is the egasimus comment, but I can't Accept a comment, if egasimus creates the comment as an answer, I'll move it. thanks